# AVG Uninstallation Vault

Tags: virus, anti-virus, uninstall, avg-antivirus

Will clicking "Remove Virus Vault Contents" during the AVG uninstallation removal process permanently delete the contents in the Virus Vault from the computer, or remove them from the vault by restoring them to the system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deletes it from the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you uninstall AVG and click "Remove Virus Vault Contents", it will delete the quarantined files in the vault, completely removing them from your PC.